# PyPSA-Eart: error in build_renewable_profiles

Tags: python, pypsa

I'm attempting to run a simulation of the African continent with PyPSA-Eart, but I'm encountering some difficulties. I've set the input countries to "africa", tutorial to "true", and cutout to "cutout-2013-era5", but I'm encountering this error:
Error in rule build_renewable_profiles:
jobid: 17
input: resources/natura.tiff, data/copernicus/PROBAV_LC100_global_v3.0.1_2019-nrt_Discrete-Classification-map_EPSG-4326.tif, data/gebco/GEBCO_2021_TID.nc, resources/shapes/country_shapes.geojson, resources/shapes/offshore_shapes.geojson, data/hydro_capacities.csv, data/eia_hydro_annual_generation.csv, resources/powerplants.csv, resources/bus_regions/regions_onshore.geojson, cutouts/africa-2013-era5.nc
output: resources/renewable_profiles/profile_solar.nc
log: logs/build_renewable_profile_solar.log (check log file(s) for error details)

After reviewing the log file, I noticed the following message: "WARNING:main:Weather data does not fully cover the requested region." Additionally, I manually downloaded the cutout files "africa-2013-era5" and "cutout-2013-era5", but encountered the same issue. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?